# Starting Android Development for an iOS Developer

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, view

I am a very experienced iOS developer; I have been programming for iOS for about 4 or 5 years and I am very used to Objective-C and View Controller-based applications. I am now trying to learn Android development so I can make cross-platform apps and I am finding it very confusing, primarily in the respect of how to programmatically create views.

I'm used to something like this:

```
UIView* aView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[aView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)];
[self.view addSubView: aView];
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do that in Android Java. Every guide I've looked at has dependency on pre-configuring the frames in XML.

I ideally want to support all screen sizes and densities, so it seems to me that the best option would be to build the views programmatically, so does anyone have a "transitioning from iOS programming to android programming guide" that they can recommend that will walk me through the steps to create a blank view and add subviews to it, like images, text fields, labels, etc.?

Comment: Do you know Java? If not, you need to buy a book on that first.

Comment: @laiello I know Java *somewhat*. I have taken some college classes on it and I am familiar with the syntax and structure of Classes, methods, instance variables, etc. I'm just not familiar with Android itself.

Comment: " I ideally want to support all screen sizes and densities, so it seems to me that the best option would be to build the views programmatically" : very bad idea, Android handles this very well with XML. Take a look here : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating Views programmatically will not at all make your honorable goal of creating an app that looks good on all screen sizes easier. 
In fact it will make your life miserable. It is error-prone, cumbersome and per se not responsive to screen sizes.

There are situations where you need to create Views programmatically, for instance if the the number or type of Views is dependent on data that you don't know beforehand, but generally creating your layouts with the XML layout files is the way to go.

The nice thing about them is that you can provide different layouts for different screen sizes, which is hard to achive programmatically.

Google has lots of [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) on the subject.

If you really want or need to create Views programmatically, just check their constructors in the docs and the methods they provide to control their looks and behaviour.

SO will also provide hints and examples.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the help. As an iOS guy, I'm used to the Interface Builder, which kind of sucks, so I guess I wrongly assumed that XML building would also suck. I'll read up. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, XML building can suck because the WYSIWYG editor that comes with Eclipse or Android Studio has it's pitfalls. But it's good enough for most basic stuff and as an eperienced programmer you'll soon be comfortable just editing the plain XML. The  code completion features of the IDEs also works in the layout XML editor.

Comment: Ah okay, so I can *programmatically* (in a sense) setup the views with XML code. That's wonderful! That will make my life easier.